# catch error: structure (127 [object] [object]) on neo4j cypher session

Tags: javascript, neo4j, passport.js

I have had a similar error before but that was caused by a syntax error in the .run statement.

I have looked this code over and over and can't find a syntax so I think something else is going on. This function is called by the passport deserializer and the value of "id" was confirmed using node-inspector. however, no matter which type of MATCH query I use, I get the same .catch error.

I have tried WHERE option and the direct option...they both work in the neo4j browser. Can someone see what I am not seeing

```
router.getUserByID = function (id, callback) {
      session
      .run ("MATCH (user {id(user) : {paramUserID}}) RETURN user",{paramUserID: parseInt(id)})
      .then (function(result)
       {
        if ( !result.records[0]) 
            {
             console.log("unknow user by id");
             session.close();
             if (typeof callback==="function") {
               return callback(null,false);
              }
            }     // end of if not found
          else
           {
              console.log("user by id found");
              session.close();
              if (typeof callback === "function") {
               return callback(null,result); 
               }
            }
        })

     .catch(function(err)
            {
            console.log("catch error: "+err);
            });        
     }  // end of get user by id
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference the Neo4j id of the node that way, you have to use a `WHERE` clause:

```
MATCH (user) WHERE id(user) = {paramUserID} RETURN user;
```

If you have an application id (almost always a good idea), then you could do:

```
MATCH (user {uuid: {paramUuid}}) RETURN user;
```

It would be better with a label though, because different entities could have the same id, and you can use a unicity constraint (which also indexes the values, so the query is faster):

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:User) ASSERT n.uuid IS UNIQUE;
// Later
MATCH (user:User {uuid: {paramUuid}}) RETURN user;
```

Comment: I did read in the neo4j docs where the node id was unstable and I plan to use "email". Also as I indicated I did try using the "WHERE" clause with the same result. After reading your answer I tried again and got the same result ...my code is:  .run ("MATCH (user) WHERE id(user)= {paramUserID} RETURN user",{paramUserID: parseInt(id)})